# Do mercurial and git store history of which changesets you've updated to?

Tags: git, mercurial, revision-history

Do mercurial and git store a record of what changesets you were on before recent calls to `update/checkout`?   Is that history stored somewhere?

A concrete use case is if you `pull/fetch` new work on a project and run into a problem with some of the new changes.  Such a history would let you update back to where you were, in order to reverse the change without trial and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As distributed, Mercurial does not store information about which revisions you had checked out previously—but there is an experimental extension as of Mercurial 3.9 called [Journal](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension) that, if enabled, does.  Note too that `hg pull` does not update to any new reference unless you tell it to, i.e., it's much more like `git fetch` than it is like `git pull`.<sup>1</sup>

Git does store this information, in the *reflog* for the special reference name `HEAD`.<sup>2</sup>  This does depend on reflogs being *enabled*; you can disable them.  The default for a normal working repository is to have them enabled.

After a `git merge` or `git rebase` (i.e., the second half of `git pull`), `HEAD@{1}` extracts the first entry in the reflog.  Assuming you did a successful merge or rebase (so the immediately-previous value of `HEAD` is the old reference), that gets you the previous `HEAD`.  If you did a rebase, and it failed and needed human assistance, the previous `HEAD` is further back in the reflog, but `ORIG_HEAD` will point to the previous commit.  The reflog for the current branch itself will also be useful.

---

<sup>1</sup>Fortunately, there are few things in the world like `git pull`, because `git pull` is a badly-designed convenience tool that's often more inconvenient than convenient.

<sup>2</sup>Whether `HEAD` is really a reference name is arguable.  For reflog purposes, it is.

Comment: Excellent! — and your answer reminded me where I'd seen it before in mercurial:  The [Journal Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension) is distributed (as experimental) with vanilla mercurial, and provides similar functionality if you enable it in .hgrc.

Comment: Ah, I'll edit the Journal Extension link into the answer.

Comment: Having tried the extension, I'll note that the implementation does not exactly match the linked documentation today.  That said, it does indeed solve this problem.  (Note, you need to enable it *before* you run into the problem — before the `hg update` — in order to have it start recording states.)